# How to find differences between multiple column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table which as questionset which has muliple questions and answers. An answer is given by multiple users. I want to find questionset ids where questions or answers between users differ. For e.g. 1 questionset does not differ because same combinations of questions and answers given by all users but questionset 2 differ.

[image]

Comment: Your sample data doesn't make sense in the context of your question - you've asserted that question-set #2's answers differ amongst users but the users, in this example, haven't answered the same questions.

Comment: Questions also can differ based on the previous answer it will change. That's the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `EXISTS` function?

```
SELECT DISTINCT questionset
FROM table_name tab1 
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM table_name tab2
        WHERE tab1.questionset = tab2.questionset
        AND tab1.question = tab2.question
        AND tab1.answer = tab2.answer
        AND tab1.user_id <> tab2.user_id )
OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM table_name tab3
        WHERE tab1.questionset = tab3.questionset
        AND tab1.question = tab3.question 
        AND tab1.user_id <> tab3.user_id )) ;
```

Comment: Although query is working it is giving timeout for running around 5000 question sets. Is there any way to optimize it?